# JSON Object Null

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I successfully deserialize JSON File and I'm getting the results but after the end of results I'm getting 'object not set to instance of an object` error

JSON File:

```
"radiant_team": {
          "team_name": "EHOME",
          "team_id": 4,
          "team_logo": 52122954231169668,
          "complete": true
        },
        "dire_team": {
          "team_name": "Team Secret",
          "team_id": 1838315,
          "team_logo": 543025270456493033,
          "complete": true

public partial class LiveLeagues
{
    public LiveGames Result { get; set; }
}
public class LiveGames
{
    public List<GameStats> games { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
}
 public class GameStats
        {
            public List<BasePlayer> players { get; set; }
            public RadiantTeam radiant_team { get; set; }
            public DireTeam dire_team { get; set; }
        }

public class DireTeam
    {
        public string team_name { get; set; }
        public int team_id { get; set; }
        public object team_logo { get; set; }
        public bool complete { get; set; }
    }

public class RadiantTeam
    {
        public string team_name { get; set; }
        public int team_id { get; set; }
        public object team_logo { get; set; }
        public bool complete { get; set; }
    }

LiveLeagues.LiveLeagues liveGames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LiveLeagues.LiveLeagues>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

    foreach (var leagues in liveGames.Result.games)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(leagues.dire_team.team_id.ToString());
           MessageBox.Show(leagues.radiant_team.team_id.ToString());  
        }
```

I tried to iterate through the JSON and test if the values will show. I tested it on MessageBox.Show and I got the result "EHOME" and "Team Secret" but after that the error comes up 'object not set to instance of an object`

Comment: Please show the complete json and the value of liveGames.Result.games.Count. I guess there is an 'empty' game at the end of your json

Comment: `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` that is most certainly wrong.

Comment: this is the JSON File i uploaded it on pastebin, can't post it on my post its too big http://pastebin.com/P8EPG41X

Comment: @JeffMercado how so? i have tried it on getting players name and id's it works just fine.

Comment: Your JSON File contains two livegames, and only the first one has a 'dire_team' and 'radiant_team' property. So for the second legues object, the dire_team will be null...

Comment: @Fortega i don't know why the other league does not show it's team details how can i resolve this?

Comment: @Nevi since it's missing from the JSON, it depends on where you get this JSON from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the json allows for games without the dire_team and/or radiant_team property, you should do null checks to make sure they are there:

```
foreach (var leagues in liveGames.Result.games){ 
  if(leagues.dire_team != null)
    MessageBox.Show(leagues.dire_team.team_id.ToString());
  else
    MessageBox.Show("no dire team for this game");

  if(leagues.radiant_team != null)      
     MessageBox.Show(leagues.radiant_team.team_id.ToString());  
  else
    MessageBox.Show("no radiant team for this game");
}
```

Or you could try using default values for these objects in the constructor of GameStats.

```
public class GameStats
    {
        public List<BasePlayer> players { get; set; }
        public RadiantTeam radiant_team { get; set; }
        public DireTeam dire_team { get; set; }

        public GameStats(){
          dire_team = new DireTeam();
          radiant_team = new RadiantTeam();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for this so ill just null checks every property? is there any non tedious way to do this?

Comment: @Nevi: see my edit. But this will not work for every json library. You should test if this works for you